# Unable to use rerender and oncomplete with apex:input file

Tags: visualforce, files, actionfunction, apexinputfile, actionregion

I have checked that apex:inputfile does not work with rerender and oncomplete tags of action function.
But I have seen there are some workaround. I tried using action region around other content, like around buttons or around all other components except apex:inputFile, but the file does not get passed to the server in that case. Do anybody have any idea about this. I cannot have a different save button for this.
Below is my code for reference.

```
<apex:form id="caseCommentForm">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit" id="Edit">
            <apex:pageMessages id="errorMsg"></apex:pageMessages>
            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              
                    <apex:actionFunction name="save1" action="{!save}" oncomplete="doClose('{!isSuccess}')" reRender="errorMsg"/> 
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="return doSave()" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn" onclick="CancelCaseComment();"/>
             
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:PageBlockSection id="CommentDetails" Title="Comment Details" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField id="isPublished" label="Public" value="{!obj.isPublished}" styleClass="isPublished"/>              
            <apex:inputField id="body1" label="Comment" value="{!obj.CommentBody}" required="true" style="width:450px;height:120px;"/>
          
            </apex:PageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Please upload your Document" columns="1">
                <br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 100px">
                            <apex:inputFile id="manualfile" value="{!fileObj.body}" filename="{!fileObj.name}" contentType="{!fileObj.contentType}"></apex:inputFile>
                        </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <br/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Why you need rerender here?

Comment: @TusharSharma  Rerender is required to refresh the error messages.Oncomplete is required to perform and check some conditions and then redirect to another page. Also I need  to add delete button to delete the selected file if  user has selected wrong file. So there also rerender will be required.

Comment: When ful page reload it will display error message if any. For that you can call method from JS.  Instead of delete button do pre upload check or after upload you can rendered it.